# ts461 op-amp: Vcc and Vdd in datasheet

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, vcc

I thought to use the op-amp TS461 in an audio circuit as a signal amplifier.
Here is the [datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/ts461.pdf). In the datasheet, for power supply, the pins are Vcc and Vdd. Due to my newbie-ness, I was expecting only one of these. Please help:

1. Is this standard? Should they not be using only one of these and then the other should be Vee or Vss?
2. Which of these is the +ve supply and which of these is the -ve supply? The Electrical characteristics table (table 3) says at the top Vdd=-2.5V, so, can Vdd be taken to be -ve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a very unusual convention, but there are clues in the datasheet:

[image]

Since the part is not advertised as having beyond-the-rail inputs (or even rail-to-rail inputs) this implies (contrary to what the previous posted answer says) that VDD is the negative supply and VCC is the positive supply.

For even more explicit confirmation, there are the operating conditions specified for the electrical characteristics table:

[image]

Comment: I should have looked at the pinout. Most op-amps have pin 4 is positive and pin 11 negative, so it supports this answer.

Comment: Looks like the manufacturer used a somewhat unconventional (at least to me) way of naming the supply pins.  Usually, I would think Vcc, Vdd, and V+ as all being the positive supply voltage pin, and V- or maybe Vss as beng the negative supply voltage pin.